# Matlab - different axes size in subplot

Tags: matlab, plot, axes, subplot

I have two graphs with different scale and I would like to use subplot. How do I set axes size  for subplot(211) and set different axes scale for subplot(212)???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[subplot](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html) returns an axes object:

```
ha = subplot(211);
plot(1:10);
set(ha, 'xscale', 'log');
hb = subplot(212);
plot(1:10);
set(hb, 'xscale', 'linear');
```

Store it in a variable and set the scale as you need.

Comment: I have a plot(x, y) and I would like to give each subplot different axes range

Comment: @MarioLIPCIK Generally in MATLAB, you can type `get(objhandle)` to get a list of properties of an object. In this case, type `get(ha)` to get a list of axes properties. What interests you is `xlim` property. You can set it using `set(ha, 'xlim', [xmin xmax])`. Go through the list to know what else you can do. You can set different range for the other axes using `set(hb, ...)`